# laravel dusk tearDown() must be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::tearDown()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk, teardown

```
public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->click('#navbarDropdown')
                    ->click('.dropdown-item');
        });


        parent::tearDown();
    }
```

When I apply the tearDown() method to my test class I get an error telling me `the  tearDown() must be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::tearDown()` What am I doing wrong?

Every time I run a test I need to login. I want to login in the setUp() method and the log out again in the tearDown, so I can execute my tests independently.

This is my setUp() method

```
use databaseMigrations;
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->seed('DatabaseSeeder');

        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/admin')
                    ->type('email', 'admin@admin.com')
                    ->type('password', 'admin')
                    ->press('Login');
        });
    }
```

The setUp() method works just fine. Even when I don't add any code to the tearDown() method, except the `parent::tearDown();`, I get an error, so what am I doing wrong in my tearDown() method?

```
public function tearDown()
    {

        parent::tearDown();
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing the `: void` on `tearDown()`:

```
public function tearDown(): void
{
  parent::tearDown();
}
```

You have `setUp()` correct, but both methods, as method of the parent class, need to be compatible and omitting the `: void` isn't.

Any time you see that error, it's best to check the source of the class you're extending. By inheritance, that is

> Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase.php

```
/**
 * Setup the test environment.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function setUp(): void
{
  ...
}
...
/**
 * Clean up the testing environment before the next test.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function tearDown(): void
{
  ...
}
```