# Laravel Passport - Feature test returns unauthorized 401

Tags: laravel, phpunit, guzzle, laravel-passport

I'm trying to test my login endpoint where a successful response would return the `access_token` among other things.

I'm using `RefreshDatabase`, so I changed the login method on the controller to retrieve the `client_secret` via a `DB` call. I tested with a `dd()` and I can confirm that the client_secret changes on each `phpunit` run in the terminal. The credentials are correct and the API endpoint works - just not when it's run via a test. For example, I have the passport tables set up on my mysql server and I can login successfully when running Postman. It's only when trying to run a test do I get a `401` error.

Here is my `AuthTest`

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AuthTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;



    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function a_user_receives_an_access_token()
    {

         \Artisan::call('passport:install');

        $user = factory('App\User')->create();

        $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/login', [
            'username' => $user->email,
            'password' => 'password'
        ]);



        $response
            ->assertJson([
                'access_token' => true
            ]);


    }
}
```

routes/api.php

```
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
```

AuthController@login:

```
    public function login(Request $request) {
        $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

        try {
            $response = $http->post(config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' =>  '2', //config('services.passport.client_id')
                    'client_secret' => DB::table('oauth_clients')->where('id', 2)->pluck('secret')[0], //config('services.passport.client_secret'),
                    'username' => $request->username,
                    'password' => $request->password
                ]
            ]);

            return $response->getBody();

        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {



            if ($e->getCode() == 400 || $e->getCode() == 401) {
                return response()
                ->json([
                    'status' => $e->getCode(),
                    'message' => 'Your email and/or password are incorrect',
                    'expanded' => $e->getMessage()
                ]);
            }

            return response()
                ->json([
                    'status' => $e->getCode(),
                    'message' => $e->getMessage()
                ]);
        }

    }
```

I took a look at this question and the accepted answer: [How to test authentication via API with Laravel Passport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113508/how-to-test-authentication-via-api-with-laravel-passport)

I am unable to use the following

```
public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    \Artisan::call('migrate',['-vvv' => true]);
    \Artisan::call('passport:install',['-vvv' => true]);
    \Artisan::call('db:seed',['-vvv' => true]);
}
```

This results in an error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Tests\Feature\AuthTest::setUp() must be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::setUp()`

Edit: I just added

```
    public function setUp() :void {
        parent::setUp();
        \Artisan::call('migrate',['-vvv' => true]);
        \Artisan::call('passport:install',['-vvv' => true]);
        \Artisan::call('db:seed',['-vvv' => true]);
    }
```

but the problem still persists

Edit again:

If I test the oauth route directly, it **passes**.

```
    public function testOauthLogin() {
        $oauth_client_id = 2;
        $oauth_client = OAuthClient::findOrFail($oauth_client_id);

        $user = factory('App\User')->create();

        $body = [
            'username' => $user->email,
            'password' => 'password',
            'client_id' => $oauth_client_id,
            'client_secret' => $oauth_client->secret,
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'scope' => '*'
        ];
        $this->json('POST','/oauth/token',$body,['Accept' => 'application/json'])
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJsonStructure(['token_type','expires_in','access_token','refresh_token']);
    }
```

But my custom endpoint that uses guzzle fails. I do not know why

Edit again:

I think the issue is with Guzzle, but I'm not sure. I found another implementation of what I'm trying to do, which is the following:

```
 public function login(Request $request) {
        $request->request->add([
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => $this->client->id,
            'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
            'scope' => '*'
        ]);

        $response = Route::dispatch(Request::create(
            'oauth/token',
            'POST'
        ));


    }
```

The above works.

Comment: I answered this question literally yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60837159/laravel-dusk-teardown-must-be-compatible-with-illuminate-foundation-testing-te/60837219#60837219. You need `: void` after `setUp()` and `tearDown()`

Comment: That isn't really the question, but thanks. Adding that to my test class did not fix my actual issue. It isn't a duplicate question. Please take your close vote off...

Comment: Yes, I did read the question, and I inferred from the final part of your question that the answer on the other question you referenced would solve your issue. Since that answer is missing the `: void` part, I figured that correcting that would solve your issue, but it seems you have more problems.

Comment: Fair enough, I should have specified that that was an aside. I added the `passport:install` on the method itself so I guess it was an irrelevant aside.