# Laravel Passport: How can I properly setup a feature test?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am trying to create a Feature test that tests getting an OAuth access token. When using Postman, everything works great (actual code) so I am confident it is in my test code I am not implementing the setup correctly.

In the past, I have run the artisan command, and simply copy/paste the `client_secret` into my `.env` file. Because I am using CI/CD, I cannot do that. I need to either:

- create an artisan command to append the `.env`
- read the secret from the `oauth_clients` table (seems the easiest route)

I've followed [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60852820/laravel-passport-feature-test-returns-unauthorized-401) to help get where I'm at, but not able to make it work.

Here is what my test looks like:

**MyFeatureTest.php**

```
use RefreshDatabase, WithFaker, DatabaseMigrations;

public function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->artisan('passport:install');
}


public function a_user_can_get_a_token()
{
    $credentials = [
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
    ];

    $http = $this->postJson('api/v1/login', $credentials);

    $response = json_decode($http->getContent());

    // dd($response);

    $http->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJsonStructure([
                'token_type', 'expires_in', 'access_token', 'refresh_token',
            ])
            ->assertJson([
                'token_type' => $response->token_type,
                'expires_in' => $response->expires_in,
                'access_token' => $response->access_token,
                'refresh_token' => $response->refresh_token,
            ]);
```

In my Controller that handles the `login` route:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->client = DB::table('oauth_clients')
        ->where('id', 2)
        ->first();
}


...


public function getOauthAccessToken($credentials)
{
    $response = Http::asForm()->post(env('APP_URL') . '/oauth/token', [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => $this->client->id,
        'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
        'username' => $credentials['username'],
        'password' => $credentials['password'],
        'scope' => '*',
    ]);

    if ($response->successful()) {
        return $response->json();
    } else {
        dd($response->body());
    }
}
```

When using postman to test my routes/controller, everything works great. I get a Barer token back as expected.

When I run my Feature test, my controller returns `null`.
Trying to troubleshoot, I've tried `dd($response->body())` above. Here is what I am getting:

```
"{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed","message":"Client authentication failed"}"
```

If I `dd($this->client->secret)`, I am able to see the key. This is super confusing as it looks like everything is working...

How can I properly set up my test so that passport is ready to go/configured when I hit the login test(s)? Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone for your suggestions!

This is what ended up working for me. Since I am the only consumer of my api, I don't need to return the entire `/oauth/token` response (although it might be helpful in the future).

**MyTest.php**

```
 use RefreshDatabase, WithFaker, DatabaseMigrations;

public function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->artisan('passport:install', ['--no-interaction' => true,]);
}


/** @test */
public function a_user_can_authenticate_using_email()
{
    $credentials = [
        'username' => 'test@email.com',
        'password' => 'password',
    ];

    $http = $this->postJson('api/v1/login', $credentials)
            ->assertStatus(200);
}
```

**MyController.php**

```
// authenticate the $credentials to get a $user object.

...

return $this->getOauthAccessToken($user);

...

private function getOauthAccessToken($user)
{
    $token = $user->createToken('My Personal Access Token')->accessToken;

    return response()->json($token);
}
```

Instead of validating I get the exact json back (would be ideal) I'm just verifying that I'm getting a 200 response back. Because my authentication is somewhat cumbersome (checking multiple db's) it was important to make sure that I was getting through everything with a 200.

Hope this helps someone!